# Up-to-date Software Design Resources

Tags: design-patterns, architecture

I am a software developer who mainly works with .NET & C#, but I carry interest in many languages.

I'm feeling a bit behind the curve with software design principles and patterns. I'm familiar with the most popular patterns, such as Inversion of Control and Object Relational Mapping, but I've learned of these ideas through books. I reckon the information must emanate from somewhere, and that somewhere must have a blog of some kind.

What are the best resources to help me stay ahead of (or on) the curve of software design?

Many thanks!

Comment: Is it bad that the first thing that tipped me off to this question being old wasn't the date, or the fact that this would be really off-topic now, but the mention of ORM and Inversion of Control? I mean, sure, both are still used now, but I haven't heard the terms themselves in a while.

Comment: Probably because only a few ORM frameworks panned out, and Inversion of Control has just been shortened to IoC, or "injection" or "container".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very good list of design principles is in the [SOLID principles](http://butunclebob.com/ArticleS.UncleBob.PrinciplesOfOod).

Staying *ahead* in this area is not about new and shiny methodologies, but about paying attention to the principles of olde, like *separation of concerns*, *coupling* and *cohesion*. Also, *test-driven development* (or *behavior-driven development*) might help you achieve better designs through evolution... But you have to know what it looks like to get there!

That said, I find that a good series of articles is in the [MSDN Magazine Patterns in Practice](http://www.google.com/#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&source=hp&q=msdn+magazine+Patterns+in+Practice&pbx=1&oq=msdn+magazine+Patterns+in+Practice&aq=f&aqi=g-v1&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=2168l4598l0l4999l15l13l0l4l4l1l336l2313l0.4.3.3l13l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=9441c9e3bb40875d&biw=1024&bih=673).

Answer (score 1):

I am no expert, but one thing that really helps me understand and stay updated with new design patterns and principles is looking at other popular projects.

Downloading a popular open source project and just going through the solution explorer and looking at how the classes are laid out is always a learning experience for me.

Comment: It would be interesting if you could mention some. I have to say that well thought out solutions are very rare, most of the time "they just barely work". However that might be because I'm mainly interested in wiered stuff, which is perhaps by definition wiered ;D

Comment: I dont know wiered :) .... but all these mentioned here are really worth a look    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/143088/open-source-c-projects-that-have-high-code-quality